# GC overhead limit exceeded when reading large pipe-separated values file

Tags: java, parsing, delimiter, large-files

I am trying to parse a large file (6.5 million rows) but am getting the mentioned out-of-memory error. I am using this same method to read other files of around 50K rows, and it works fairly quickly. Here it runs extremely slowly, then fails with the error. I originally had 2 GB dedicated to intelliJ, which I changed to 4 GB (-Xmx4000m), then 6 GB (-Xmx6000m), and still finish with the same error. My computer only has 8 GB RAM so I can't go any higher. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
public static List<UmlsEntry> umlsEntries(Resource resource) throws 
 IOException {
 return CharStreams.readLines(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream())).stream().distinct()
    .map(UmlsParser::toUmlsEntry).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static UmlsEntry toUmlsEntry(String line) {
 String[] umlsEntry = line.split("|");

 return new UmlsEntry(umlsEntry[UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_CONCEPT_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[LANGUAGE_OF_TERM_COLUMN_INDEX], umlsEntry[TERM_STATUS_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_TERM_COLUMN_INDEX], umlsEntry[STRING_TYPE_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[IS_PREFERRED_STRING_WITHIN_THIS_CONCEPT_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_ATOM_COLUMN_INDEX], umlsEntry[SOURCE_ASSERTED_ATOM_INDENTIFIER_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[SOURCE_ASSERTED_CONCEPT_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[SOURCE_ASSERTED_DESCRIPTOR_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[ABBREVIATED_SOURCE_NAME_COLUMN_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[ABBREVIATION_FOR_TERM_TYPE_IN_SOURCE_VOCABULARY_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[MOST_USEFUL_SOURCE_ASSERTED_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN_INDEX], umlsEntry[STRING_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[SOURCE_RESTRICTION_LEVEL_COLUMN_INDEX], umlsEntry[SUPPRESSIBLE_FLAG_COLUMN_INDEX],
    umlsEntry[CONTENT_VIEW_FLAG_COLUMN_INDEX]);
 }
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace. Which line caused the error?

Comment: ah i didn't copy it, i will run it when i go out for lunch, it uses all my memory so i can barely do anything else. will be in touch soon...

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat the lines a few at a time to avoid using up all available memory, since the file doesn't fit in memory. `CharStreams.readLines` confusingly isn't streaming. It reads all lines at once and returns you a list. This won't work. Try `File.lines` instead. I suspect that you will get into trouble with `distinct` as well. It will need to keep track of all hashes of all lines, and if this balloons too far you might have to change that tactic as well. Oh, and `collect` won't work either if you don't have enough memory to hold the result. Then you might want to write to a new file or a database or so.

Here is an example of how you can stream lines from a file, compute distinct entries and print the md5 of each line:

```
Files.lines(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/my/file"))
            .distinct()
            .map(DigestUtils::md5)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you run into trouble detecting distinct rows, sort the file in-place first and then filter out identical adjacent rows only.

Comment: yeah it turns out my machine isn't powerful enough to hold the entire list without quitting like all my programs. can load all the lines fine, but adding to the list, once it gets over 1 million, becomes VERY slow.